# Why does this code make the QImage lose its alpha channel?

Tags: qt, qimage, alpha-transparency

I'm trying to understand why the code below changes the QImage in Qt. It's not meant to do anything (yet), it's just for testing. When I run the code on an image with alpha, the alpha channel is lost and replaced by a black background.

```
QImage image;
image.load("image.png");

for (int y = 0; y < image.height(); y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < image.height(); x++) {
        QColor c = QColor::fromRgba(image.pixel(x, y));
        c.setHsv(c.hue(), c.saturation(), c.value());
        image.setPixel(x, y, c.rgba());
    }
}
```

Here is the result when I comment out the line `image.setPixel(...)`:

[image]

And here is the result with the `image.setPixel(...)` line:

[image]

I would expect my code to do no change on the image. Any idea why it's doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the documentation of [setHsv()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qcolor.html#setHsv), you will see that alpha is set by default to 255 (or 1.0 for the float version) if you don't explicitly specify it.

Perhaps using the line `c.setHsv(c.hue(), c.saturation(), c.value(), c.alpha());` will resolve your problem.